# dark mode in laravel while using sass

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, webpack, sass

I'm using sass preprocessor on my laravel project.

on all of my stylesheets, i've used css variables for all colors. all of the variables are stored in 'resource/sass/_variables.scss' and imported in the begining of all stylesheet files.

the inside of '_variables.scss' file is something like this:

```
$primary-background:#1b203d;
$primary-box-color:#2a2b4a;
$primary-border-color: #7277c422;
$secoundary-box-color: #393a66;
$primary-box-shadow: #1a1b2f;
......
```

and also in my stylesheet i've used variables like this:

```
@import 'variables';
#sidebar{
    background-color: $secoundary-box-color;
    border:1px solid $primary-border-color;
    // .....
}
```

now i'm trying to implement dark mode switch using css variables.

I have no idea how to change css variables, consider it that all my stylesheets (with variables) will be compiled and i have no longer access to css variable on the frontend!

Comment: You can create a second file `_variables-dark.scss` and another stylesheet that imports it e.g. `app-dark.scss` and add that entry in your webpack.mix.js file as well. Then depending on the user's theme you can load one or the other. However to make things easier for you ensure there's only one place where `_variables.scss` is imported otherwise you'd need a second version of each file that imports `_variables-dark.scss`. Since dark mode is usually given as an option to users you need to have both versions of stylesheets pre-compiled and ready

Comment: that seems to be the best way, can you explain more about how to choose between `_variable-dark.scss` and `_variables.scss` to import based on user selection?

Answer (score 1):

you can use css custom properties to assign colors

```
//_variables.scss
$lightTheme: #fff;
$darkTheme: #000;

//style.css
@import 'variables';
:root {
    --theme: #{$lightTheme};
}

body {
    background-color: var(--theme);
}

body.dark {
    --theme: #{$darkTheme};
}
```